# Add contacts to Marketing list on CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm trying to build a Workflow that add a Contact to a marketing list.

Everything seems to be fine,  but when the code finishes firing, and I go to the marketing list -> members the contact is not in the list.

```cs
public class ContactToMList : CodeActivity
    {
        [Input("Contatto")]
        [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> contact { get; set; }

        [Input("Marketing List")]
        [ReferenceTarget("list")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> MList { get; set; }

        [Input("Inserimento")]
        public InArgument<bool> inserimento { get; set; }

        bool action = false;
        private static IOrganizationService myService = null;
        private static Log_Entity log = new Log_Entity(string.Empty, myService);
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            try
            {
                ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

                // Create the context
                IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

                // Create the Organiztion service
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                myService = service;
                log.WriteLog("");
                // Get the target entity from the context
                Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];


                Guid contactiId = contact.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Id;
                Guid ListId = MList.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Id;
                bool insert = inserimento.Get<bool>(executionContext);


                // Prepare DataContext by using AutoGenerated cs file
                XrmDataContext datacontext = new XrmDataContext(service);

                var MyContact = (from c in datacontext.ContactSet where c.ContactId == contactiId select c.Id).ToArray();
                var MyList = (from l in datacontext.ListSet where l.Id == ListId select l).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                // tutti i membri della lista di marketing
                var members = (from m in datacontext.ListMemberSet where m.ListId.Id == MyList.ListId select m.EntityId.Id).ToArray();




                foreach (Guid id in members)
                    if (MyContact.FirstOrDefault() == id)
                        action = true;



                if (insert && !action)
                {

                    AddListMembersListRequest AddMemberRequest = new AddListMembersListRequest();

                    AddMemberRequest.ListId = ListId;
                    AddMemberRequest.MemberIds = MyContact;
                    // Use AddListMembersListReponse to get information about the request execution 

                    AddListMembersListResponse AddMemberResponse = service.Execute(AddMemberRequest) as AddListMembersListResponse;
                    //service.Update(MyList);

                }
                else if (!insert && action)
                {

                    RemoveMemberListRequest RemoveMemberRequest = new RemoveMemberListRequest();
                    RemoveMemberRequest.ListId = ListId;
                    RemoveMemberRequest.EntityId = MyContact.FirstOrDefault();
                    // Use AddListMembersListReponse to get information about the request execution 
                    RemoveMemberListResponse RemoveMemberResponse = service.Execute(RemoveMemberRequest) as RemoveMemberListResponse;
                   // service.Update(MyList);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLog(ex.Message);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This code could be refined with more Linq statements...however, it also looks like it would be pretty straightforward to debug.  Have you walked through the code to see if the values are what you expect when the `service.Execute(` is called?

Comment: It's ok on remove, but do not add any account.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the reply, please check it as an answer. Otherwise, do tell what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aren't you erasing your values for `AddMemberRequest.MemberIds` after you set it?

EDIT:
Ok, I think I found it this time.  Your `public InArgument<bool> inserimento { get; set; }` is likely the culprit.

In this case, your Workflow activity expects this to be defined upstream of the call to this Workflow.  It's very likely statically set and never changed for both the Insert and Remove instances.  If this is true, then it's being essentially hard coded for the Insert case, which makes the `else if (!insert && action)` evaluate to True for Remove and the `if (insert && !action)` evaluate to False for the Insert.

Since the code does work for Remove, it's reasonable to assume the `bool action` is working; therefore, I would start by looking into the other bool variable.

Let me know if I've missed it.  (or if I'm right, I wouldn't mind the green check mark.)

Comment: no! Sorry, my mistake on copy/paste!  That's the good code. :)